# How to pprint json data in clojure?

Tags: json, clojure

I'm new in clojure programming. I just want to know, How can I pprint my json data.
I tried like this:

```
user=> (clojure.pprint/pprint {"a": "apple", "b": "boy" "c": "cat"})
;; {"a": "apple", "b": "boy", "c": "cat"}
```

I want my output should look like

```
   {"a": "apple",
    "b": "boy",
    "c": "cat"}
```

Can anyone tell me, How can I get pprint output of json data?

Comment: I don't understand; none of the data in your question is valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You need a library [org.clojure/data.json "0.2.6"], to work with json.

Examles:

```
(clojure.pprint/pprint (json/write-str {"a" "apple", "b" "boy" "c" "cat"}))
=> "{\"a\":\"apple\",\"b\":\"boy\",\"c\":\"cat\"}"

(clojure.pprint/pprint (json/read-str "{\"a\":\"apple\",\"b\":\"boy\",\"c\":\"cat\"}"))
=> {"a" "apple", "b" "boy", "c" "cat"}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, you want your data to be formatted with newlines after each key-value pair. If so, I would suggest that you look into the [formatting options](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/0a6810ab3484b5be0afe4f505cd724eb5c974a09/src/clj/clojure/pprint/pprint_base.clj#L19-L97) provided by `clojure.pprint`. Namely, you can set `*print-right-margin*` to a sufficiently small value to force each pair to appear on a new line. If you omit this binding, `pprint` will use the default value of 72, and any form larger than that should be formatted in this way automatically.

```
(binding [clojure.pprint/*print-right-margin* 16]
  (clojure.pprint/pprint
    {"a" "apple" "b" "boy" "c" "cat"}))

;; {"a" "apple",
;;  "b" "boy",
;;  "c" "cat"}
```